# Spring Autowire Resttemplate As Factory Bean?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

When I debug my code I see that creating Resttemplate takes time. What happens about performance if I autowire it via Spring? Does Spring offers a factory pattern for injected beans?

Comment: What do you mean by _Does Spring offers a factory pattern for injected beans?_ Spring is an IoC container. It manages your beans. Create a `RestTemplate` bean and inject it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Spring does offer a factory pattern for injected beans, but in your case since Spring default bean behaviour is to be a singleton, you would only need to configure your RestTemplate once, and then inject into any class that it is needed in